# Checkbox state with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have list of checkboxes in my jsp page.Based on Main checkbox i have to check/uncheck all child check boxes.

1)Take i have 10 child checkboxes and have  main checkbox.When i check Main checkbox,i able to select all child checkboxes.if user unselect any child checkbox,i able to unselect 
main checkbox.so here out of 10 childcheckboxes,i unselect 1 checkbox ,based on this i unchecked main checkbox.

But here my Question,if user checks that checkbox again,so here my status is selected all 10 checkboxes.So i should even checks the main checkbox too.

Comment: I think you should figure out all the logic for the page *before* you try to figure out how to do it all with JavaScript.  (Maybe you have figured it out, but it's not clear, and it sounds like a very strange interaction setup. What are the checkboxes for?)

Comment: @Pointy- huh? That is not strange interaction where the checkbox becomes checked when everything is selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add onclick handlers to the checkboxes.
2. Keep a count.
3. If it is checked add 1, if it becomes unchecked subtract one.
4. If the total equals the number of checkboxes, check the check all checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough guide to how to do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var checkboxCheck = (function() {
  var boxes;
  var mainCb;

  // If all checkboxes checked, return true
  function allChecked() {
    var i = boxes.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (!boxes[i].checked) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // If value is in array, return true
  function oneOf(value, array) {
    var i = array.length;
    while(i--) {
      if (array[i] == value) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Main function
  return function(evt, el) {

    // Get the element that was clicked on
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    // Initialise boxes if not done already
    if (!boxes) {
      boxes = [];
      var o = el.getElementsByTagName('input');

      for (var i=o.length; --i;) {

        if (o[i].type == 'checkbox') {
          boxes.push(o[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    // Initialise mainCb if not done already
    if (!mainCb) {
      mainCb = document.getElementById('mainCb');
    }

    // If the click was on one of the checkboxes
    if (oneOf(target, boxes)) {

        // If they're all checked, check mainCb
        // otherwise uncheck mainCb
        mainCb.checked = allChecked(boxes);

    // If the click was on mainCb      
    } else if (target == mainCb) {

      // Set all checkboxes to same state as mainCb
      for (var j=boxes.length; j--;) {
        boxes[j].checked = mainCb.checked;
      }
    }
  }
}())
</script>

<fieldset onclick="checkboxCheck(event, this)">
<label for="main">Check all<input type="checkbox" id="mainCb" value="0"></label>
<br>
<label for="cb0">0<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" value="0"></label>
<br>
<label for="cb1">1<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1"></label>
<br>
<label for="cb2">2<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2"></label>
</fieldset>
```